# How to display angular data in Tiles format rather than a tabular fomat

Tags: html, css, angularjs, mvvm, grid

I am making an Angular application in which I have to display data like in Tiles, the kind of tiles we see on netflix, [image]

But all I have made up is like a tabular format, [image]

Not sure How to display data in a Grid/tiles format, 
The result of the search should be displayed below the search box as a set of tiles. 4 tiles across.
Any help or suggestion is really appreciated.

```
<table class="table">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th><a>ID</a></th>
            <th><a>Gender</a></th>
            <th><a href="" ng-click="orderByField='name'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">name</a></th>
            <th><a href="" ng-click="orderByField='email'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">email</a></th>
            <th><a href="" ng-click="orderByField='city'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">city</a></th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in mainVm.users | filter: searchKeyword | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort" id="trow">
          <td>{{user.id}}</td>
          <td>{{user.gender}}</td>
          <td>{{user.name}}</td>
          <td>{{user.email}}</td>
          <td>{{user.city}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: are you using angularMaterial or bootstrap? or just plain CSS?

Comment: Just Angular and BooTstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="user in mainVm.users | filter: searchKeyword | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort" id="trow">
    <!-- Your data --> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

In your css something like below

```
li{
 float:left;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your question is too broad, I've made a simple fiddle that you can follow to achieve your goal.

http://jsfiddle.net/ov90m3mu/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 tile" ng-repeat="tile in items">
      <h3>
        {{tile.name}}
      </h3>
      <p>
        {{tile.description}}
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Instead of table, I've used bootstrap grid system. I've also added a box-shadow effect to separate the tiles.

For smaller screens, you may want less tiles per line. [I recommend a good read](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/).

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it with span and in-line block with a CSS box like so:

```
<style>
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}
</style>
     <span style="display:inline-block" class="mydiv" ng-repeat="f in friends">Name: {{f.name}}<br />Phone: {{f.phone}}<br>Age: {{f.age}}</span>
```

Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6DIGzHfG1X4xEUCD5Rtk?p=preview)